# unable to create docker image in ubuntu

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a folder in an ubuntu VM called "MovieFlix" that contains a dockerfile a python flask app and a "templates" folder with html templates inside. I have managed to build a docker image with the same dockerfile successfully twice but I had to delete it in order to edit my python file . The third time I try to build my docker image the image is not build and I get

```
Package python3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  dh-python

E: Package 'python3' has no installation candidate
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

My DockerFile :

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER bill <bill@gmailcom>
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN apt-get install -y bcrypt  
RUN pip3 install flask pymongo flask_bcrypt
RUN pip3 install Flask-PyMongo py-bcrypt
RUN mkdir /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/templates
COPY webservice.py /app/webservice.py
ADD templates /app/templates 
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python3" , "-u" , "webservice.py" ]
```

I tried installing python3-pip but it is already installed in my ubuntu VM
I would appreciate your help . Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1):

Run below commands in order :

```
1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install dh-python
```

Comment: I do not have to also change my python3 installation in my dockerfile right ?

Comment: I did the above and tried to build my image it did not work . I changed "python3 " to "dh-python" in my dockerfile and got the errors i edited above

Comment: I got The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dh-python : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install dh-python' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: my python version is Python 2.7.17 in ubuntu

Comment: Good to use `python 3`. Lot of broken package issues will go away I guess. There seem to be minor glitch or some compatibility mismatch.

Comment: I also have python 3.6.9 installed but it seems that it is not my default python version . Is there a quick way to change that ?

Comment: This might help : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu

Comment: I changed the default python version but still got the same results

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED : I deleted all inactive docker containers and build my image again with the same code